# Multithreading pthread errors

Tags: c, multithreading, compiler-errors, pthreads

Im trying to create a multithreaded application in C for Linux with pthreads library that makes an approximation of pi using infinite series with N+1 terms.Variable N and T are passed from the command line. I am using the Nilakantha approximation formula for pi. N is the upper limit of the number sequence to sum and T would be the # of child threads that calculate that sum. For example if I run command "./pie 100 4". The parent thread will create 4 child threads indexed 0 to 3. I have a global variable called vsum that is a double array allocated dynamically using malloc to hold values. So with 4 threads and 100 as the upper bound. My progam should compute:

```
 Thread 0 computes the partial sum for i going from 0 to 24 stored to an element vsum[0]
 Thread 1 computes the partial sum for i going from 25 to 49 stored to an element vsum[1] 
 Thread 2 computes the partial sum for i going from 50 to 74 stored to an element vsum[2] 
 Thread 3 computes the partial sum for i going from 75 to 99 stored to an element vsum[3]
```

After each thread makes calculations. The main thread will compute the sum by adding together all numbers from vsum[0] to vsum[T-1].

Im just starting to learn about threads and processes. Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Code I wrote so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>


double *vsum;
int N, T;

void *PI(void *sum) //takes param sum and gets close to pi
{
  int upper = (int)sum;
  double pi = 0;
  int k = 1;

  for (int i = (N/T)*upper; i <= (N/T)*(upper+1)-1; i++)
  {

    pi += k*4/((2*i)*(2*i+1)*(2*i+2));

    if(i = (N/T)*(upper+1)-1)
    { 
      vsum[upper] = pi;
    }
   k++;
  }
 pthread_exit(0);
}





int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
     T = atoi(argv[2]);
     N = atoi(argv[1]);
  if (N<T)
   {
     fprintf(stderr, "Upper bound(N) < # of threads(T)\n");
     return -1;
   }
     int pie = 0;
     pthread_t tid[T]; //thread identifier
     pthread_attr_t attr; //thread attributes
     vsum = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));//creates dyn arr
//Initialize vsum to [0,0...0]

  for (int i = 0; i < T; i++){
  {
   vsum[i] = 0;
  }




  if(argc!=2) //command line does not give proper # of values
  {
     fprintf(stderr, "usage: commandline error <integer values>\n");
     return -1;
  }
  if (atoi(argv[1]) <0) //if its is negative/sum error
  {
      fprintf(stderr, "%d must be >=0\n", atoi(argv[1]));
      return -1;
  }

//CREATE A LOOP THAT MAKES PARAM N #OF THREADS 

      pthread_attr_init(&attr);

   for(int j =0; j < T;j++)
   {
     int from = (N/T)*j;
     int to = (N/T)*(j+1)-1;
   //CREATE ARRAY VSUM TO HOLD VALUES FOR PI APPROX. 
      pthread_create(&tid[j],&attr,PI,(void *)j);
 printf("Thread %d computes the partial sum for i going from %d to %d stored to an element vsum[%d]\n", j, from, to, j);

   }
  //WAITS FOR THREADS TO FINISH
   for(int j =0; j <T; i++)
   {
     pthread_join(tid[j], NULL);
   }

  //LOOP TO ADD ALL THE  vsum array values to get pi approximation
   for(int i = 0; i < T; i++)
   {
     pie += vsum[i];
   }

    pie = pie +3;

   printf("pi computed with %d terms in %d threads is %d\n",N,T,pie);


   vsum = realloc(vsum, 0);
   pthread_exit(NULL);

 return 0;
}
```

Here is the error I dont see that I get on my program: What am I missing here?

```
            ^
pie.c:102:1: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
 }
```

When I try to run my program I get the following:

```
./pie.c: line 6: double: command not found
./pie.c: line 7: int: command not found
./pie.c: line 8: int: command not found
./pie.c: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./pie.c: line 10: `void *PI(void *sum) //takes param sum and gets close to pi'
```

Comment: The undefined references are because you aren't following your platform's instructions for compiling/linking pthreads code. Most likely, you need to pass the `-pthread` flag.

Comment: You are not really trying to run your C file directly from within the shell, do you?

Comment: I compile the code using gcc -std=c99 -pthread pie.c. I then type on the command line ./pie.c 100 4

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at logic of your code, but I see following programming errors.

Change

```
pthread_create(&tid[j],&attr,PI,j);
```

to

```
pthread_create(&tid[j],&attr,PI,(void *)j);
```

`pthread_create()` takes 4th param as `void *` which is passed to the thread function.

---

Also fix your thread function `PI` to use passed parameter as `int` like

```
void *PI(void *sum) //takes param sum and gets close to pi
{
  int upper = (int)sum; //don't use `atoi` as passed param is int.
  ... 
  //your existing code
}
```

---

The 3rd error is for line

```
realloc(vsum, 0);
```

By passing 0 to re-allocate, you are effectively just freeing `vsum`, so you can just use `free(vsum)`. If you indeed want to reallocate you should take the new allocated memory returned by the function something like `vsum = realloc(vsum, 0);`

Comment: That, and `if(i = (N/T)*(upper+1)-1)` should probably not be an assignment but a comparison, and `for (int i = 0; i < T; i++){{ vsum[i] = 0; }` probably has a start brace too much, and... In other words, in addition to your answer, turning on all warnings is a good idea :)

Comment: Touched it up! Also when I run the program it gives me `pie.c:102:1: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input` which says that my`double` and `ints` before the `Sum` function are commands not found. Is there some stupid mistake I made in the beginning lines of this code?

Answer (score 0):

The Syntax of pthread is

pthread_create(threadId, threadAttribute, callingMethodName, parameters of calling method);

Ex:

```
void printLetter( void *p)
{
int i=0;
char c=(char *)p;
while (i<10000)
{
 printf("%c",c);
}
}

int main()
{

pthread_t thread_id;
char c='x';
pthread_create (&thread_id, NULL, &printLetter, &c);
pthread_join (thread_id, NULL);
return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Passing a pointer to a local variable as a parameter to another thread is probably not a good idea. If it goes out of scope or is changed before the thread is actually started, things may very well badly and semi randomly fail.